# `alphabetic` style label for entries without author

Tags: biblatex

I would like to use the Biblatex `alphabetic` citation style, which produces citation labels like `[Knu]`. However, two of my references are websites, and they have no author. Currently they are displayed as `[]`. Is there a way to put a specific string as the label in this case? I have tried setting the `labelalpha` key manually, but that doesn't work.

MWE: file `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\begin{document}
Go check~\cite{texse}!
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

file `mwe.bib`

```
@online{texse,
 url={http://tex.stackexchange.com},
 title={Awesome website},
 labelalpha={TexSE},
}
```

Current output:
[image: MWE]

Desired output: `[TexSE]` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `label` field:

```
@online{texse,
 url={http://tex.stackexchange.com},
 title={Awesome website},
 label={TexSE},
}
```

[image]